# Closing files and folders ussing batch

Tags: file, batch-file

Im trying to close a file (not an application) ussing batch. I namely need particular files and folders closed to execute a delete option. i have noted that open files and folders will not delete.

Comment: Note of caution: In the general case it is never a good idea to randomly close handles in other applications. Be prepared for crashes and the like and then have fun.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a Windows environment, there are a lot of utilities to do that. See for example http://www.thefreecountry.com/utilities/deletelockedfiles.shtml